# HSQL in memory database for Junit repository class

Tags: java, junit, hsqldb

I have to write JUNIT for repository class using HSQL DB.
I am not supposed to use any SQL command to load the data into HSQL DB.

Instead I need to use one external jar called `abc.jar` which will load all the schema and data from production database into HSQL.

`abc.jar` was working fine as standalone i.e. exporting schema and table from real database into HSQL .

In the current package I added `abc.jar` as dependent. When I call a method in `abc.jar` to export the data in `@before` of repository jUnit I'm getting HSQL connection exception.

Is it a possible approach?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check the StackOverflow's help on asking questions first, please. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.

Comment: Can you show us your code and the exception please ?

Answer (score 0):

It is a possible approach.

The connection URL in both the standalone setup and the test setup must be an absolute URL. And the export of data must occur in the same JVM process. If you are using a `file:` database, the path to database files must be absolute. If you are using a `mem:` database, the paths are absolute, provided they are used in the same JVM process.